# Loop em objeto com JQuery each

Tags: jquery

Estou fazendo loop em um objeto com JQuery each e não estou tendo sucesso.

Objeto abaixo gerado via PHP:

```
{"status":"hasP",
 "flag":null,
 "qtProcess":null,
 "code": null,
 "message": [{"id":"1","email":"teste@hotmail.com"},{"id":"2","email":"teste1@hotmail.com"}]}
```

Código JQuery para capturar o obejto e gerar uma tabela(parte onde gera uma falha):

```
$.each(data, function(index, value){                    
    table +='<tr><td>' + value.message.id + '</td>';
    table +='<td>' + value.message.email + '</td></tr>';
});
```

Gera o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: value.message is undefined
```

Comment: Dê um `console.log(value)` e veja se realmente existe o campo message; e como message é um array, não será possível acessar o id diretamente como está fazendo, teria que ser algo do tipo `value.message[0].id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não está lendo o objeto corretamente, o array está no atributo `message`:

```js
var table = "";

var data =  {"status":"hasP","flag":null,"qtProcess":null,"code":null,"message":[{"id":"1","email":"teste@hotmail.com"},{"id":"2","email":"teste1@hotmail.com"}]}

$.each(data.message, function(index, value){
  table +='<tr><td>' + value.id + '</td>';
  table +='<td>' + value.email + '</td></tr>';
});

console.log(table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Só mudei o código na parte colocada pelo Glauber e funcionou. $.each(data.message, function(index, value){
  table +='<tr><td>' + value.id + '</td>';
  table +='<td>' + value.email + '</td></tr>';
});

Comment: @RRV você estava querendo fazer o loop com o objeto todo, mas o array esta no atributo message, o que indica um array são os colchetes `[ ]` e as chaves `{ }` dentro dos colchetes são as linhas.

Answer (score 0):

Acessa o objeto **message** diretamente no objeto **data** com javascript puro.

```
for (index in data.message) {
        table +='<tr><td>' + index.id + '</td>';
        table +='<td>' + index.email + '</td></tr>';
}
```